# Installing pzmq with Cygwin

Tags: python, windows, gcc, cygwin, jupyter-notebook

For two days I have been struggling to install pyzmq and I am really not sure what the issue is.

The error message I receive after:

```
pip install pyzmq
```

is:

```
 error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I have gcc installed.

```
which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
```

Python is installed at the same location. I am really struggling to find a solution.

Edit: Adding to the output from the error, here is the output that describes the error further:

```
 bundled/zeromq/src/signaler.cpp:62:25: fatal error: sys/eventfd.h: No  such file or directory
  #include <sys/eventfd.h>
                         ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip- build-INbMj2/pyzmq/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), 
__file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-n8hQ_h-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-INbMj2/pyzmq
```

Edit Two: Following installation instructions from https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq/issues/391

```
pip install pyzmq --install-option="fetch_libzmq"
```

Yields :

```
#include <sys/eventfd.h>
                         ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Next:

```
pip install --no-use-wheel pyzmq --global-option='fetch_libzmq' --install-option='--zmq=bundled'
```

Yields:

```
#include <sys/eventfd.h>
                         ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: Looks like they offer MSI installers on their [GitHub downloads page](https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq/downloads).

Comment: The error you're getting isn't that gcc is not installed or not found. It's that gcc encountered an error during compilation of native components of pyzmq. You'll need to dig into the output/logs to figure out why gcc encountered an error. When you do, please add those logs to this question and I'm sure we can figure out a proper answer.

Comment: @AlexLaties Just added more information from the output

Comment: Have you seen this ? https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq/issues/391 Looks similar to what you're getting

Comment: @rlb.usa I did come across that when trying to install and edited the post to display that output. Same error continues to arise.

Comment: Hey, @JakeDeVries. This question just helped me a ton! Was like, wait that's Jake; I know him! haha

Answer (score 11):

python3-zmq is a package in cygwin. Assuming you are trying to install for python 3, if you are using apt-cyg package manager, you can install it using

```
apt-cyg install python3-zmq
```

Comment: This should be the first one. Hope more people see this.

Answer (score 9):

Installing IPython in Cygwin with pip was painful but not impossible. This comment by @ahmadia on the zeromq GitHub project gives instructions for installing pyzmq: https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq/issues/113#issuecomment-25192831

The comment says it's for 64-bit Cygwin but the instructions worked fine for me on 32-bit. I'll summarize the steps assuming install to /usr/local. First download and extract the tarballs for zeromq and pyzmq. Then:

```
# in zeromq directory
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib/pkgconfig
./configure --without-libsodium
make
gcc -shared -o cygzmq.dll -Wl,--out-implib=libzmq.dll.a -Wl,--export-all-symbols -Wl,--enable-auto-import -Wl,--whole-archive src/.libs/libzmq.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive -lstdc++
install include/zmq.h  /usr/local/include
install include/zmq_utils.h  /usr/local/include
install cygzmq.dll /usr/local/bin
install libzmq.dll.a /usr/local/lib

# in pyzmq directory
python setup.py build_ext --zmq=/usr/local --inplace
python setup.py install --zmq=/usr/local --prefix=/usr/local

# finally!
pip install ipython[all]
```

After that, `pip install ipython[all]` just works, notebook included.

Comment: I don't know why someone down voted this. It worked to me. Thanks.

Comment: Worked for me, except `libzmq.a` was in `libs/` rather than `src/.libs/`.

Comment: Worked for me too, with Peter O's change.  Also, I was able to install in a virtualenv by replacing all instances of /usr/local with $VIRTUALENV

Answer (score 8):

Ran into this problem myself.  After a lot of research came up with the following:

cygwin does not support the `eventfd` functionality.  If you check in `/usr/include/sys` you'll notice that `eventfd.h` is not present.  I'm not sure why cygwin doesn't support this -- but I was able to find https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2012-10/msg00198.html which insinuates as much and along with the missing header file my conclusion is we're SOL until such time as that gets added.

For more insight here's the github repo for glibc that contains eventfd.h:
https://github.com/lattera/glibc/tree/a2f34833b1042d5d8eeb263b4cf4caaea138c4ad/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/sys

Here's a listing of the core devel files included with cygwin (note eventfd is one of the missing files):
https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi?grep=cygwin-devel&arch=x86

BTW -- If you're trying to install ipython notebook (that's how I encountered this error), as a work around I used wakari.io which provides a web interface to the ipython notebook.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was indeed trying to install Ipython Notebook.

Answer (score 7):

This is an old one but I've came across the same error message today. Solved by simply installing `libzmq5` and `libzmq-devel` (runtime and development) using Cygwin default installation procedure.

Comment: worked for me with cygwin-x64 and allowed me to do a pip install jupyter

Comment: Is it the command ?   Anything to be modified for python3 world ?                                                                              setup-x86_64.exe -q -P libzmq5-devel

Comment: installing the libzmq5 and libzmq-devel worked for me as well